# How to get min/max price in a collection Firestore Flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a room collection for all the rooms in a hotel. I would like to get the minimum price in all that collection.

My current method code:

[image: My current method code]

Firestore Collection:

[image: Firestore Collection]

Comment: Aren't you missing a rooms specifier in your collection? Should be instance.collection("rooms/single/room")?

Comment: please no images of code

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("rooms")
                            .orderBy("price")
                            .limit(1)
                            .get();
```

Try this to get lowest one)

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("rooms")
                                .orderBy("price",descending: true)
                                .limit(1)
                                .get();
```

Try this to get very expensive one
*note your collection in documents must be with same name(rooms)